# send image in push notification

Tags: codenameone

I've only sent texts in push notification till now. Can I send images as well in cn1? And how can I open a specific screen through clicking push notification? Up to now, it only opens the home screen of the app.

[image]

Comment: I'm sure you can

Answer (score 0):

There is an RFE for supporting rich push notifications [here](https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues/2208). It's currently pretty bare of use cases so I suggest adding those as it's scheduled for the next update.